# Is it correct to say 'and as well' instead of 'as well as'?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, sentence

Because I often see **as well as** or **and** in sentences, is the following sentence correct?

It is suitable for you **and as well** for me.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe it's actually syntactical (although if both must exist, *and for me as well* sounds much better)—but mostly redundant and would likely be edited to remove one or the other. Or to change it to the form I suggested.

Comment: 'As well' is usually used at the end of a sentence, as in Jason's example. You could say 'and also for me' as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is suitable for you and as well for me. (**incorrect**)

It is suitable for you,  and for me as well. (afterthought)

It is suitable for you and for me. (poetic)

It is suitable for you and  me. (normal)

It is suitable for both of us. (usual)

It is suitable for you and also for me. (your preference takes priority)